# lotus notes db.search method and dynamic @formula

Tags: lotus-notes

can i search dynamic @formula with db.search method dynamic formulas ?

if i do:

```
Set coll=db.Search({SELECT  type="office" & form="note"},Nothing,0)
```

the method retrive the correct collection, but if i do:

```
dim search as string
search ="office"
Set coll=db.Search({SELECT  type=search  & form="note"},Nothing,0)
```

OR

```
dim search as string
search =InputBox( "prompt","title")
Set coll=db.Search({SELECT  type=search  & form="note"},Nothing,0)
```

the method do not retrive the correct collection of doc.
Is there the possibility to search dynamic @formula using db.search method ?
thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
dim search as string
search =InputBox$( "prompt","title")
Set coll=db.Search({SELECT  type="} & search & {"  & form="note"},Nothing,0)
```

You want to use "search" as variable and not as search string

Comment: Your InputBox returns a Variant containing a string! You have to use InputBox$

Comment: for the moment i'm using search="office" without inputbox

Comment: Put your search formula to a variable and debug your code. In the debugger you can see if your formula has the correct form

Comment: yess ! i follow your advice and i resolve the problem ! thank's ! great !

Comment: In db.Search there is no need for a "SELECT" statement. `{type="} & search & {" & form="note"}` would be totally sufficient